# Firebase implementation without googleservices.json file in xamarin

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-analytics

I have to implement firebase in 2 configurations Debug and Release.
This is the reason I have removed json files and wrote code line this:

for configuration 1-

```
var env1 = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                            .SetApplicationId(myId)
                            .SetApiKey(myKey)
                            .SetStorageBucket(appspot.com)
                            .SetProjectId(myPID)
                            .SetDatabaseUrl(MYURL)
                            .Build();

var app1 = FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(Application.Context, env1, "Debug");
analytics= FirebaseAnalytics.GetInstance(app1.ApplicationContext);
```

For configuration 2-

```
var env2 = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                            .SetApplicationId(myId)
                            .SetApiKey(myKey)
                            .SetStorageBucket(appspot.com)
                            .SetProjectId(myPID)
                            .SetDatabaseUrl(MYURL)
                            .Build();

var app2 = FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(Application.Context, env2, "Release");
analytics= FirebaseAnalytics.GetInstance(app1.ApplicationContext);
```

Here either it is giving error like missing_google_id or firebase is not initialized.

I have tried adding string value in xml file for android,still same error.
To acieve my goal I have also tried adding multiple json files in different directories as per the link below

[Xamarin firebase different google-services,json for different build configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54368589/xamarin-firebase-different-google-services-json-for-different-build-configuratio/54368935#54368935)

but it seems it still looks for json file in root folder..

So how to implement firebase without or with json file for multiple environments

Answer (score 0):

There definitely is no way to report analytics data from multiple `FirebaseApp` instances in a single app. See [Firebase Analytics (Two projects) for single app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43761824/firebase-analytics-two-projects-for-single-app).

If I remember correctly, Google Analytics for Firebase always reports analytics for the default `FirebaseApp` instance. The best reference I found for that is [Use multiple firebase accounts in single android app for google analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45546833/use-multiple-firebase-accounts-in-single-android-app-for-google-analytics), but if someone has a more authoritative source I'd love to hear.

If that is the case, since each build is *either* Debug *or Release, you could initialize only the relevant `FirebaseApp` instances for the specific build target.